# Drop columns with similar names with over 50% nan in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large pandas data-frame [df] with hundreds of column names.
I want to drop all columns that have over 50% NAN values but only those columns that have the word "test" in the columns title. Is there an easy way to do this & thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you provide sample dataframe?

Comment: On this DF, only test12 and test13 would be dropped:[link]http://i64.tinypic.com/hry2w7.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC  you can do something like this:

```
In [122]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'test':np.NaN, 'asd':0,'test 1':[0,1,np.NaN,3,4]})
df

Out[122]:
   asd  test  test 1
0    0   NaN     0.0
1    0   NaN     1.0
2    0   NaN     NaN
3    0   NaN     3.0
4    0   NaN     4.0

In [138]:
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('test')]
to_remove = cols[df[cols].isnull().sum() > len(df)/2]
to_remove

Out[138]:
Index(['test'], dtype='object')

In [140]:
df.drop(to_remove, axis=1)

Out[140]:
   asd  test 1
0    0     0.0
1    0     1.0
2    0     NaN
3    0     3.0
4    0     4.0
```

So firstly we get the list of cols that contain 'test' using [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains):

```
In [142]:
df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('test')]

Out[142]:
Index(['test', 'test 1'], dtype='object')
```

then we test this subset for `NaN` values using [`isnull`]:

```
In [143]:
df[cols].isnull()

Out[143]:
   test test 1
0  True  False
1  True  False
2  True   True
3  True  False
4  True  False
```

if we [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas.DataFrame.sum) this, it converts the boolean values to int 1 and 0:

```
In [144]:
df[cols].isnull().sum()

Out[144]:
test      5
test 1    1
dtype: int64
```

we can then create a boolean mask by comparing this against the half length of the df:

```
In [145]:
df[cols].isnull().sum() > len(df)/2

Out[145]:
test       True
test 1    False
dtype: bool
```

We can then filter this to get the cols to drop:

```
In [146]:
cols[df[cols].isnull().sum() > len(df)/2]

Out[146]:
Index(['test'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Just wondering if a similar approach can be taken to fill NANs with 0 (ZERO)?

Comment: You mean [`df.fillna(0)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)?

Comment: yes indeed - how do I ensure that it's just applied again to the "cols" that contain the work "test"?